# pscp, more than one remote source not supported

Tags: windows, pscp

Could someone tell me why this is giving the error please?

Copying from Windows to Unix.

```
C:\Windows>pscp.exe e:\onbase\outgoing\fa\file.txt user@server.utk.edu:/data/banint/DocMgmt/kbande/in/Fav/file.txt -pw password
More than one remote source not supported
```

Eventually I need:

```
C:\Windows>pscp.exe e:\onbase\outgoing\fa\*.txt user@server.utk.edu:/data/banint/DocMgmt/kbande/in/Fav/ -pw password
```

(i.e., with a `*.txt` wildcard in the source parameter
and a directory name as the destination). 
I can't even get a single file to copy. I do have two other scheduled tasks copying from Unix to the same Windows server using `pscp` and they work fine.

Why won't this work?

Comment: Like nearly all commandline programs on both Windows and Unix, you need to put **option** arguments, in this case `-pw passwd`, **BEFORE** **operand** arguments, in this case the local and remote (or vice versa) filenames.

Comment: I had it that way originally, then it prompts me for the password after the command.

Comment: Did it say `Access denied` first and then prompt for password? If so the one you gave on the command line was sent but was rejected by the server.